# Downloading a Blob by Filename in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I know that I can grab a blob by BlobKey, but how do I get the blobkey associated with a given filename?

In short, I want to implement "get file by filename"

I can't seem to find any built-in functionality for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a blob by its file name. You need to query the Datastore for entities of type `BlobInfo`. These entities have a property `filename`.

Note, however, that file names are not guaranteed to be unique: you may get more than one result. You can then use the property `creation` to find the latest blob.

For more information, read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass

Answer (score 1):

Every blob you upload, creates a new version of that blob (with that filename) in the blobstore. Ofcourse you can delete the old version(s) of the blob, if you uploaded a new version. But to make sure you have the latest version of a blob (of a filename) you have to store the filename in the datastore and make a reference to the latest version. This reference holds the blob_key.